# Verifying Using Boolean Types

Tags: java, boolean, verify

I'm trying to verify the value of an imported class.

I'm sure I'm not being as clear as I can be. Below is a link to the zip file which holds the class I'm trying to access.

[zip file for class](http://www.mediafire.com/download/2w4wjg57y6js0qd/hidden.zip)

So far I have:

```
 public class findHidden {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    double n=0;
    boolean a = hidden.MysterySquare.inSquare(n);
        System.out.println("a = " +a);

    while (a == true){
        n = n + .1;
    }//end while

    System.out.println("n = " +n);


}//end main

}//end class
```

What I want to do is pass the value of "n" through:

```
 boolean a = hidden.MysterySquare.inSquare(n);
```

and increment "n" by

```
 n = n + 0.1;
```

each time

```
 boolean a
```

is true. And return the value of "n" when "a" is False.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class findHidden {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean a=true;
    double n=0;
    do{
        a = hidden.MysterySquare.inSquare(n);
        System.out.println("a = " +a);
        n = n + .1;
    }while (a);//end while
    System.out.println("n = " +n);

  }//end main
}//end class
```

I am guessing you are trying to increment `n` until the return value is `false`?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I'm trying to do. I tried your program, but received an error on "while (a)"

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! Haha. I usually do only while loops and thought a curly bracket would fix it, but or course, I was wrong. Thank you, again Dexters!